# how to know which image related to which content item in drupal

Tags: drupal

I have drupal and i like to know which image in the database related to which content item?
in other worlds "Select Join for contents (node,page,story,etc) and images"
what are the tables that i have to use??

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what modules you use to attach images to your nodes.

- The data that drupal store about files, is in the `files` table.
- The data for the nodes (content) is in the `node` table.
- The data for the connection can be in a few places, if you use CCK which is the most normal thing to use, there is functiona that will generate this for you, as it depends upon settings how the data is stored:

  ```
  $field = content_fields('FIELD_NAME');
  $db_info = content_database_info($field);
  ```

What you will need will probably be some of these:

```
$db_info['columns']['nid']['column'] // the table for the nid, used to join node table
$db_info['columns']['fid']['column'] // the table for the fid, used to join files table
$db_info['table'] // The table the data is stored in
```

Comment: ok what are the fields that i can use to join between "files" and "node"
how to know that record X in "files" is related to record "Y" in "node"
Thanks for your help

Comment: @alaa There is no direct connection, you have to use a join table. That table can be anything dependent on module use and configuration like explained above.